# Can someone help me Retrieve file from SQL Server vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado

Can someone help me?!i am having a problem with my project
i have a table named Document have this fields ( id_d , type_d, date_create_d , way , #Nbr_Som ) 
and Nbr_Som is a foreign key references to a table named fonctionnaire 
 when i print document For example(work certificate),
the document registred as a file PDF in a record for exemple (D:\BTS\Document ) ,
so when i search for a work certificate  on a forme on (VB.net) by date of year or month 
I want to extract all this files

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

this code the form that contains the crystalrepotviewer :

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim r As New RCAttestationDeTravail
        Dim dt As DataTable

```
    dt = Form1.PFE_GRHDataSet.EnseignantS
    r.SetDataSource(dt)

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r
    CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{EnseignantS.Num_SOM} = " & Form1.Num_SOMTextBox.Text


    ''

    Dim rapport As New RCAttestationDeTravail
    Dim filename As String
    Dim str As String = ":"
    filename = "C:\Users\Salha\Documents\AttestationDeTravail" & DateString & "+" & Now.Hour & "," & Now.Minute & "," & Now.Second & ".pdf"
    rapport.SetDataSource(dt)
    rapport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, filename)




End Sub
```